# Lettuce in Spring Integration 5: RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint no really blocking

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-integration

I've just switched from Spring Boot 1.X to Spring Boot 2.0 RC1, so now I'm using Spring Integration 5, which uses Lettuce as the default Redis library.

I have a `RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint` that I want to wait until a new messages arrives, so I set the receive timeout to 0, which means it should block until something arrives. This worked with Spring Integration 4, however, with Lettuce there is a default connection timeout of 60 seconds, so I get the following exception:

```
Failed to execute listening task. Will attempt to resubmit in 5000    milliseconds.
org.springframework.dao.QueryTimeoutException: Redis command timed out; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException: Command timed out
  at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:70)
  at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:41)
  at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:44)
  at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:42)
  at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.convertLettuceAccessException(LettuceConnection.java:257)
  at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceListCommands.convertLettuceAccessException(LettuceListCommands.java:490)
  at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceListCommands.bRPop(LettuceListCommands.java:409)
  at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultedRedisConnection.bRPop(DefaultedRedisConnection.java:478)
  at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultListOperations$5.inRedis(DefaultListOperations.java:215)
  at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations$ValueDeserializingRedisCallback.doInRedis(AbstractOperations.java:59)
  at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:224)
  at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:184)
  at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:95)
  at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultListOperations.rightPop(DefaultListOperations.java:211)
  at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundListOperations.rightPop(DefaultBoundListOperations.java:154)
  at org.springframework.integration.redis.inbound.RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint.popMessageAndSend(RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint.java:195)
  at org.springframework.integration.redis.inbound.RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint.access$200(RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint.java:58)
  at org.springframework.integration.redis.inbound.RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint$ListenerTask.run(RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint.java:340)
  at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:53)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException: Command timed out
  at io.lettuce.core.LettuceFutures.awaitOrCancel(LettuceFutures.java:114)
  at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisAsyncCommands.select(AbstractRedisAsyncCommands.java:1185)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at io.lettuce.core.FutureSyncInvocationHandler.handleInvocation(FutureSyncInvocationHandler.java:52)
  at io.lettuce.core.internal.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:80)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy156.select(Unknown Source)
  at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.getDedicatedConnection(LettuceConnection.java:888)
  at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceListCommands.bRPop(LettuceListCommands.java:407)
  ... 13 common frames omitted
```

What is the recommended way with Lettuce to have a blocking `brpop` operation without running into timeouts (and getting this execptions)? I could increase the connection timeout using `spring.redis.timeout`, but this would affect all connections.

Answer (score 0):

Lettuce is a non-blocking client based on netty and NIO. The latter two have some significance as socket read timeout (known from `SocketInputStream`) is not applicable.

Lettuce exposes a command timeout to protect synchronous calls against infinite wait. It makes sense to have a slight lower timeout on `RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint` (say 50 seconds if your `spring.redis.timeout` is 60 seconds).

The stack trace above shows a timeout in the `SELECT` command. This happens before `BRPOP`. It looks as if `spring.redis.timeout` was set to `0` (no timeout at all).

Comment: Yes, I set the `spring.redis.timeout` to `0`, as a test because I thought that would also mean that there is no timeout. So with Lettuce I do not have a real blocking call to brpop? Then those exceptions will always appear unless I increase the timeout. Meanwhile, I've switched back to Jedis.

Comment: I'd phrase it that way: There's no infinite wait until you set the timeout to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. The call is still blocking. Applying regular polling (every 30 seconds or so) is much more friendly than a single block that just sits there and does nothing. Regular activity prevents dropped network connections and keeps the connection alive.